# Selenium unable to locate element when logged in

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, xpath, element

When I try to click on an element using Selenium it only works if I am not logged in the website, otherwise I get this message: "no such element: Unable to locate element".

If I remove the log in sequence from the code it works, the problem is at the last **driver.find_element_by_xpath** line.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


url = "https://rocket-league.com"

driver.get(url)
 
agreebutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="acceptPrivacyPolicy"]')
agreebutton.click()

time.sleep(1)

agreebutton2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qc-cmp2-ui"]/div[2]/div/button[1]')
agreebutton2.click()

login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/a[1]')
login.click()

email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/main/section/div/div/div[1]/form/input[2]')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/main/section/div/div/div[1]/form/input[3]')

email.send_keys('xxx')
password.send_keys('xxx')

login2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/main/section/div/div/div[1]/form/input[4]')
login2.click()

driver.get("https://rocket-league.com/player/Sun_dance")

time.sleep(1)
decline = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="declineNotifications"]')
decline.click()

time.sleep(1)
comments = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/section/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]')
comments.click()



while True:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to scroll to the element.

For example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

found = False
while found == False:
    try:
        comments = driver.find_element_by_xpath('your xpath')
        found = True
    except:
        ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
```